# Permutations of different coloured cubes ordered

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A bag contains $17$ identical cubes except for their colour, with four coloured orange, six coloured blue and seven coloured white.  How many different arrangements of these cubes are possible when $3$ are drawn from a bag and placed in a line?

Would it be $3 \times 3 \times 3$?

Comment: Would it be 3 times 3 times 3?

Answer (score 0):

How many possibilities are there for the first ball? 3

How many for the second? 3

How many for the third? 3

All balls are independent (since there are always more than 3 balls of the same color)

Thus the answer is 3*3*3 = 27.